# PagerTabSlider: content of slider shows after sliding and pageTitleStrip never shows the text just blue line

Tags: android, xml, pagertabstrip, pagertitlestrip

I was following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) link for creating viewPager with Pager title strip but on running app it never shows the content in tab, on changing to pager tab strip it is showing the content but only after sliding. What I am doing wrong?
Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

HomePagerAdapter mHomePagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    // ViewPager and its adapters use support library
    // fragments, so use getSupportFragmentManager.
    mHomePagerAdapter =
            new HomePagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mHomePagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new HomeObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(HomeObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Object " + position+1;
            case 1:
                return "Object " + position+1;
            case 2:
                return "Object " + position+1;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

and here is the xml file with pager and tabStrip

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: instead of creating a new fragment inside getItem(), consider returning from an array. The array should be already initialized with new fragments and pass it to the constructor of the adapter.

Comment: That doesn't solves the problem and moreover i dont have any problem in creating fragments